# wcf service domain to domain connection for post or get request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, cross-domain

Work on wcf service.Have some services are in one host,request on domain my services are invoke perfectly,recently i change my hosting and domain but want to remain my existing domain ,request on existing domain want to invoke new hosting services,is it possible? bellow pic may describe in  detail
[image]

Want to complete scenario-2's cycle?is it possible?

Comment: Yes.  Every connection has a client and server.  The server starts first and listens for connections on a endpoint in local computer usually IPAny on a particular post number.  The client connects to server using a server IP address/name.  So you have to define  The server and client for each connection.  When you have a domain connecting to a domain one domain must be a server and the other a client.  The client domain will have to implement a retry algorithm if server domain isn't not running.

Comment: @ jdweng,Thanks for your reply.There is one problem when client request to old-domain,old-domain forward request to new-domain then new-domain connect with host.New-domain always get the request.Method=get not any post.

Comment: Direction is always with respect from the client to the server.  So  get is the client getting post is client putting.  Once you define which domain server is going to be the client and which domain server is the server the definition of get and put obvious.

Comment: @jdweng,sorry for lack of my knowledge will you please show me some syntax where to define the client and the server.

Comment: Each line you have drawn is a connection.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  So the connection is really a TCP connection.  There are two definitions of client. One at the TCP layer where you have a client and server. Then at the application layer client and host. This adds to the confusion. Your domain is a two port application with client-client connections, client-host connections, client-domain connections.  The Domain-Domain connection is a TCP connection where one Domain is the client and the other Domain is the server. The client is the master sending commands the server the slave.